# For android failure in getting text content of web site using 2-textniews and button

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I write program using 2-textview and one button to get textcontent of specfic website you write it in the first text view , and put text content in the second textview ,,,

But it dont work , the failure may be in this part of code - i checked every thing , it works alone good-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     final EditText Enter  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Enter);

       CharSequence web = Enter.getText();
    // CharSequence web = "http://www.google.com" ;
       final  String link = web.toString()  ;


            Button Press = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Press);
     Press.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v ) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, link ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show(); 

          new DownloadTextTask().execute(
                link);


        }
                });
}
```

Comment: Post DownloadTextTask class